# ern create-miniapp fails on Windows machine

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli, walmart-electrode

```
Hi everyone,

I am new to mini apps but I followed the documentation of [Electrode native]    
(https://native.electrode.io/v/v0.31/quick-start/getting-started) and [this]    
(https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode-native).I am facing same issue again and     again. My 
installation versions are -
electrode-native: 1.0.17
ern platform: 0.40.0
node version - 9.1.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1

I am trying to create a new project using ern create-miniapp MovieListMiniApp but         getting 
this error. The yarn file is already at this location .ern\versions    \0.40.0\node_modules\ern- 
core\node_modules\.bin\yarn but its continuously telling me
```

'Error: spawn .ern\versions\0.40.0\node_modules\ern-core\node_modules.bin\yarn ENOENT
    events.js:196
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
    Error: spawn C:\Users.ern\versions\0.40.0\node_modules.bin\yarn ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    errno: -4058,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'spawn C:\Users.ern\versions\0.40.0\node_modules.bin\yarn',
    path: 'C:\Users.ern\versions\0.40.0\node_modules.bin\yarn',
    spawnargs: [ 'info', 'test-miniapp', 'versions', '--json' ]
    }'

```
Please help me. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Please add more detail for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot and researched much but found no luck. So ultimately I find out that the problem was with Window machine . When I tried on mac machine worked fine and the root cause was that Electrode Native is still not very mature and its not compatible with Windows architecture. So better use mac or in generic Linux based machine until the mini app team fix it.